# WordPress plugin installation not possible for admin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, permissions, admin

I've got a WordPress installation of a friend which was recently hacked. I fixed many malicious files, but no admin user is allowed to install new plugins or even update installed plugins or the whole WordPress system.

I already tried to us

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

in config file, but it didn't work.

Any ideas what I could try?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you check the owner and  permissions of folders (wp-content/plugin) ? Can you upload a file on the medias ?

Comment: Hello Bazaim, yes, I just uploaded a picture.

Comment: Why can't you install new plugins? Are you seeing any PHP error / warning messages at all?

Comment: If a server was hacked, it's not yours anymore. Take it down and restore from a backup. See [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) for more info.

Comment: I don't see any errors. There is just no button "Install Plugin". I can only see an overview with installed plugins which I can activate and deactivate. But it's possible to upload plugins via ftp and activate them after that.

Answer (score 0):

If found the solution.
Someone added the following lines into wp-config.php:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
```

Setting those to false solved my problem.